# Automating Apache Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost

I plan to implement a feature on my website where users can point their domain to sub domain provided by my service.

> Sub Domain provided to John by my service is **john.myservice.com**
>
> John bought this domain **www.john.com** and wants to map it to
>   **john.myservice.com**

I know this can be done with Virtual Hosts if I am using Apache server but what am I interested to know is if is there an easy way to achieve this without me writing PHP stuff to update **vhosts** file every time user register with my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use wildcard/dynamic subdomains so you would just have one virtual host entry and it would work with any subdomain. Take a look at http://joshduck.com/blog/2010/07/13/dynamically-define-subdomains-with-apache/ to see how to set it up.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks!